# Html not making a border

Tags: html, css

I have this style

```
<div style="width: 285px; float: right; border: 1px;">
```

I am expecting there to be a border, but there isn't.  Did I do something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using `border-width`. Use `border:1px solid black` instead (or something similar).

Answer (score 3):

If you check the CSS reference you will see that `border` requires 3 parameters:

```
border: [width] [style] [color]
```

### [border Definition and Usage](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border.asp)

> The border shorthand property sets all the border properties in one declaration.
>
> The properties that can be set, are (in order): **border-width, border-style, and border-color.**
>
> It does not matter if one of the values above are missing, e.g. border:solid #ff0000; is allowed.

#### See also

- [border-width](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border-width.asp)
- [border-style](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border-style.asp)
- [border-color](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border-color.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Have to give it a type and a color like `border: 1px solid #000`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify all three border attributes, then you get default values. For the width this happens to be `medium`. For the style this is `none`, which means you get no border, no matter what the width is. I'm not sure that CSS defines a name for the default colour, but Firefox uses the current text colour.